# Subtract days from a date in the form of a string

Tags: scala, date, datetime, jodatime, datetime-format

I have a date in the form of a string like below

**"08/08/2017 11:43"**

I was trying to subtract a day from the above date string so the final output would be **"07/08/2017 11:43"**

I tried it with the below code

```
   val x = "18/8/2017 11:43"
   val formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
   val dt = formatter.parseDateTime(x);
   println(dt.minusDays(1))
```

But, the output that I got is **2017-08-17T11:43:00.000-07:00**

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the formatter for both parsing and formatting for output.

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

val x = "18/8/2017 11:43"
val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d/M/yyyy HH:mm")

val dt = LocalDateTime.parse(x, formatter)
val res = dt.minusDays(1).format(formatter)  //res: String = 17/8/2017 11:43
```